# IntelliJ Idea opens gradle folder instead of the project

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm trying to import a GitHub project, specifically, this one : [timtiemens/secretshare](https://github.com/timtiemens/secretshare) using IntelliJ Idea.

The git import works fine, at which point the IDE builds the project using gradle, which works fine.

However, when I actually open the project, only the gradle directory in the project is opened, ie, .../secretshare/gradle. The other directories, like src, are just not there in the IDE, even though they're present in the project folder - I can see them with explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Delete the idea files created by inteillj

Run gradlew idea

Open the project again and choose use gradle wrapper settings.

Comment: Any idea how to enable `gradle plugin` after opening project? It's just disabled, you're not importing `gradle project`.

Comment: you can do in settings -> gradle .

Comment: Under Project level settings heading -> choose default gradle wapper.
Then refresh gradle

Comment: I don't have it, check my [snapshot](http://postimg.org/image/gzf1q2pdn/). Do I need to have items in `Linked Gradle project` heading?

Comment: I m using intellij 14. What is the version of intellij you are using? 
Whichever the version, use import project option instead of open project. This works as well.